# AngularJS - Dynamic URLs for new page

Tags: angularjs, url, dynamic

I am AngularJS beginner so sorry for this silly question. I am working on a page called menu.html which has severals links of food categories such as Noodle, Soup, Sandwiches. When user click on any of those links it will lead to a page that list the food that are relevant to the category and with different URL. For example, click on "Noodle", the url of the new page will be menu/Noodle.html. Would you please tell me how to do it with AngularJS? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to include angular-route.js file for angular.
Refer this. https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading

```
angular.module('myapp',[]).
  config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '/menu/Noodle.html', controller: HomeController });
      $routeProvider.when('/about', { templateUrl: '/pages/about.html', controller: AboutController });
      $routeProvider.when('/privacy', { templateUrl: '/pages/privacy.html', controller: AboutController });
      $routeProvider.when('/terms', { templateUrl: '/pages/terms.html', controller: AboutController });
      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  }]);
```

Change the url according to your needs.